# facebook graph api fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I got a path in Graph API and I'd like to convert it to an FQL query. is there any possible way to proceed it with only one query?

`me?fields=
photos.limit(1500).fields
(
    name,
    created_time,
    source,
    from,
    likes.limit(1500)
),
albums.limit(1500).fields
(
    photos.limit(1500).fields
    (
        name,
        source,
        likes
    ),
    name,
    likes.limit(1500),
    place,
    description,
    updated_time,
    cover_photo,
    from
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible in one query, this should be apparent from the number of field expansions you are attempting in Graph API. This *might* be possible with some multi-queries and batch calls.